# Condition in list - Python

Tags: python, clause

I am working in python and I have this list

```
for i in range(0, len(state1)):
    observations = [{'state_transitions': [{'state': state1[i],
                                            'action': action[i], 
                                            'state_': state2[i]},],
                     'reward': 0},]
```

I would like to put the for clause inside the observations, something like this (but this is giving me an error):

```
observations = [
    for i in range(0, len(state1)):
        {'state_transitions': [{'state': state1[i],
                                'action': action[i],
                                'state_':state2[i]},],
        'reward': 0},]
print observations;
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I think you want list comprehension if I understand what you're saying. The first bit of code would overwrite `observations` with every iteration by the way.

Comment: You cannot put a for loop inside a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish (creating a list based on the results from a `for` loop) is called a *list comprehension*. Syntax is as follows: `my_list = [do_something(item) for item in my_iterable]`.

Which gives:

```
observations = [
   { 
      'state_transitions': [
          { 'state': state1[i], 'action': action[i], 'state_':state2[i] },
       ],
        'reward': 0
    } for i in range(0, len(state1))
]
print(observations)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python does feature a for clause that can go inside list declarations - but it is placed *after* your expression - so this would work:

```
observations = [{ 
    'state_transitions': [{ 
         'state': state1[i], 'action': action[i], 'state_':state2[i]
          }],
    'reward': 0
   } for i in range(0, len(state1))
]
```

Besides that, Python's `for` is designed for higer elvel interations - if what interests you is each item in the sequence, and not the variable `i` itself, you can use the `zip` call to yield you one item of each sequence:

```
observations = [{
    'state_transitions': [{ 'state': st1, 'action': act, 'state_':st2}],
    'reward': 0
    } for st1, act, st2 in zip(state1, action, state2)
]
```